# Change Year, Month, and Day columns into one or into datestamp in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columnns: `col_tx_year`, `col_tx_month`, `col_tx_day` which I already define as variables.

I want to concatenate the three columns together or to make a timestamp with them.

```
 df_tx_all = df_tx_all[
   [
     col_tx_year,
     col_tx_month,
     col_tx_day col_tx_customer_id,
     col_tx_distributor_id,
     col_tx_product_family,
     col_tx_gross_sales_quantity,
     col_tx_gross_sales_valuei,
     col_tx_net_sales_value,
     col_tx_discount_values
   ]
]


df["time_stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_tx_all[col_tx_year, col_tx_month, col_tx_day])
```

It's creating a new column in my df but with it returns NaT as a value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_datetime` can accept the data frame, only if you named it correctly

```
df_tx_all = df_tx_all[['col_tx_year',
                           'col_tx_month',
                           'col_tx_day']]
df_tx_all.columns=['year','month','day']

df["time_stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_tx_all)
```

Comment: @Simre `pd.to_datetime(df_tx_all[['col_tx_year', 'col_tx_month', 'col_tx_day']].astype(str).sum(1),format='%Y%m%d')`